# Making AJAX call back in ASP.NET with jQuery

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, vb.net, asp.net-ajax

> I accept both C# and VB.NET

If you visit this http://www.eol.org/pages/983558 and then click on the link like the image below you'll see in-line pop-up DIV which displays a busy status of Ajax callback before it displays the information. So, the information is not there yet until you click on the link.

[image]

I'd like to do the same but ASP.NET and jQuery. If there's any place to help me get started on the right track? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

[Using jQuery to directly call ASP.NET AJAX page methods](http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "PageName.aspx/MethodName",
  data: "{}",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(msg) {
    // Do something interesting here.
  }
});
```

I think this is probably a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

yes u can use roberts code to send ajax request to server side code and additionally u can use beforeSend callbck function where u will display ur hidden div with loading.. message and in success function u will actually put the data into that div.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "PageName.aspx/MethodName",
  data: "{}",
  beforeSend: function()
  {
     //display hidden div with loading.. message
  },
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(msg) {
    // remove loading.. message and put actual data to the div
  }
});
```

u can use error callback to display error message in the same div if ajax call fails for some reason. u can learn more about $.ajax function [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)